# How to list all changes done to the lvm2 snapshot

Tags: 18.04, lvm

just like in the title, is it possible to list all changes that were saved/recorded within the snapshot?

let's assume:
I have changed `/etc/network/interface` 3 days ago. 
On the next day, I installed a new package (let's say `cuda-10` under `/usr/locale/cuda-10/`). 
And today I deleted gparted (which was installed before the snapshot was made) with `sudo apt-get remove gparted` or `sudo apt-get purge gparted`

Is there a way to list all files affected by these actions? I am sure `LVM` keeps track of changes like that in one form or another (copies the to-be-changed / to-be-deleted files into the snapshot volume or sth like that), but how to list that "unformal record"? There should be a way, shouldn't there?

---

My configuration:

`Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` on four partitions:

1. `512 [Mib]` | `fat32` | flags: `boot`, `hidden`, `esp`
2. `5.00 [Gib]` | `ext4` | flags: `hidden` | mount-point: `/boot`
3. `20.00 [Gib]` | `linux-swap`
4. `900.00 [Gib]` | `lvm2-pv` | flags: `lvm`

   - volume group: `vg_ubuntu`

     - logic volume: `lv_ubuntu`: `850.00 [Gib]` | `ext4` | mount-point: `/`
     - snapshot: `lv_ubuntu_snap_00`: `50.00 [Gib]` | `ext4`